# Not able to connect Web Socket

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, starscream, swifter

I'm using "Swifter" as my local HTTP Server. 
I'm using "Starscream" for WebSockets.

Unfortunately getting `websocket is disconnected: Optional("The operation couldn’t be completed. (Starscream.WSError error 1.)"))` when i'm trying to connect.

I tries accessing localhost from browser and it looks like Http Server is working fine.

Below is the code that I'm working on:

SimpleServer:

```
import Foundation
import Swifter

class SimpleServer{

    let server: HttpServer = HttpServer()

    public func startServer(){
        do {
            server["/hello"] = { .ok(.htmlBody("You asked for bhuvesh \($0)"))  }
            try server.start(8000)
        }
        catch{
            print("Server could not be started")
        }
    }

}
```

ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import Starscream

class ViewController: UIViewController, WebSocketDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    var socket: WebSocketClient!
    var simpleServer = SimpleServer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        simpleServer.startServer()

        socket = WebSocket(url: URL(string: "ws://localhost:8000")!)
        socket.delegate = self
        socket.connect()
    }

    func websocketDidDisconnect(socket: WebSocketClient, error: Error?) {
        print("websocket is disconnected: \(error?.localizedDescription))")
    }

    func websocketDidReceiveMessage(socket: WebSocketClient, text: String) {
        print("got some text: \(text)")
    }

    func websocketDidReceiveData(socket: WebSocketClient, data: Data) {
        print("got some data: \(data.count)")
    }

    func websocketDidConnect(socket: WebSocketClient) {
        print("websocket is connected")
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling `ws://localhost:8000` from your iOS code ? That won't work. You have to put your local server's ip address

Comment: @MayRestinPeace: I replaced localhost with "127.0.0.1" but still I'm getting the disconnected error. Is "127.0.0.1" wrong IP for the simulator on which the server is running.

Answer (score 0):

Im having the exact same problem. Have you tried connecting to it with your Mac and websocat? 
If it fails there two then its probably something about your server if not you probably have the exact same problem as me.